# Running script for x session from console

Tags: xorg

I use a usb keyboard with my laptop.  It has a layout that's different from
the builtin, so I have script to switch between them.  But if I forget to switch before unplugging, I have no super.  Now I'm in a different room, and I can't be bothered to get my keyboard.  I can't get to a terminal in this x session without super, but I can switch to a different console.  But if I try to execute the script there, it says `cannot open display 'default display'`.  Can I run it *for* the open x session from the console?

PS: the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall xcape
if lsusb | grep HHKB ; then {
        setxkbmap us,gr \
                -variant carpalx-plus-intl,daedalus \
                -option grp:win_space_toggle \
                -option lv3:rwin_switch \
                -option altwin:meta_alt \
                -option shift:breaks_caps \
                -option lv5:lsgt_switch_lock
        xmodmap ~/.xmodmap/hh
        xcape -e "Shift_L=F13;Shift_R=F13;Super_L=Prior;Hyper_L=Prior"
} &
else {
        setxkbmap us,gr \
                -variant carpalx-plus-intl,daedalus \
                -option grp:win_space_toggle \
                -option lv3:ralt_switch \
                -option altwin:meta_alt \
                -option shift:breaks_caps -option lv5:lsgt_switch_lock
        xmodmap ~/.xmodmap/apple
        xcape -e "Control_L=Escape;Shift_L=F13;Shift_R=F13;Alt_L=Escape;Alt_R=Escape"
} &
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your DISPLAY variable before running the script.

Try:

```
DISPLAY=:0  yourscriptname
```

Comment: Didn't work.  If logged in as same user, there was no output. If logged in as root, it said `cannot open display ":0" // no protocol specified`.

Comment: You can test the X connection to see if DISPLAY is working using something like "DISPLAY=:0 xdpyinfo" which should print display info

Comment: Perhaps the script to change the input device is not working after the USB device was unplugged? Maybe it only works when it is plugged in. Can you post the script that modifies the super key. Maybe it's not done in a reversible operation way?

Comment: I tested this now in the same tty, where it works normally.  I also confirmed that `DISPLAY=:0 notify-send test` works from a different tty.

Comment: I was assuming your script was using something like xinput or setting x keymaps. But perhaps you're using a gnome or kde  DBUS tool? In which case there could be other dbus related variables you need to set instead of the DISPLAY

Comment: No, I'm using xmodmap and setxkbmap. (And i3.)

Comment: A good thing to try is save your environment from a terminal in your proper session using env > file.text then in your tty you can try loading that before running your command.

Comment: After seeing the script, surprised it's not working.Good luck

Comment: How do I load the saved env?

Comment: Could it be that user doesn't have permission for lsusb in that case it would always set the second keyboard

Comment: No, it's the same user.

Comment: To load the saved env, in your shell, use "source file.text" but I don't think it will be much help now